# How to increase the number of workspace/desktop in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, desktop

I’m using Ubuntu 22.04 and I have 4 workspaces used already. Is there any way to increase the number of workspaces/desktop to more than 4?

I’ve searched this already and some people suggest installing some extensions and tweaks but unfortunately it’s not compatible with Ubuntu version 22.04.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/)?

Comment: I guess this depends on Gnome, KDE Plasma or whatever you use as your desktop environment. What do you use then?

Answer (score 3):

In `Settings` - `Multitasking` you have workspaces options. They may be dynamical - so new workspace appears when you used all of them and disappear when left empty, or you can select fixed number of workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces 9
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).